# Хранение и доступ к большому многомерному динамическому массиву

Tags: c#, массивы, .net

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом лучше всего хранить многомерный динамический массив( размером от 120Гб до 8 - 20 Тб), а так же получать доступ к его элементам, не загружая при этом весь массив в оперативную память?

Главное условие - быстрый доступ чтения к элементам массива, остальное неважно. На крайний случай можно любой язык программирования, не только C#.

Comment: А где по-вашему хранится массив изначально? :

     не загружая при этом весь массив в оперативную память?

Comment: изначально он создается в оперативной памяти, будет заполняться данными, дальше когда размера ОП не будет хватать, мне его надо сохранить и как то работать с ним с жесткого диска, возможно ли такое?

Comment: ОП - это, в смысле ОЗУ, верно? @Merlin, вот вы ведь, наверняка, не новичок в программировании, но это все переворачивает с ног на голову:

    когда размера ОП не будет хватать, мне его надо сохранить и как то работать с ним с жесткого диска

Это ж абсурд! Т.е вы предполагаете хранить в массиве +1000000 значений !? Вам это не кажется странным? C# довольно гибкий язык, большинство "черной" работы он берет на себя, в отличие от C++, к примеру. Но то, что вы пытаетесь сделать, разработчики C# не могли предвидеть =)

Comment: @Аsen Нет, не кажется. Во всякие технологии OLAP многомерных БД не хотелось бы углубляться, поэтому и спрашиваю .

Comment: @Merlin, просто так поступать нельзя в принципе. Поэтому вам бы лучше рассказать о своей задаче.

Comment: А что значит "не загружая весь массив в оперативную память"? Вам его нужно где-то хранить в промежутках между разными сеансами работы или это просто забота о том, чтобы при выполнении программы он уместился в RAM? Если второе, то сейчас это проблемы операционной системы, а не Ваши. Если первое, то масса вариантов, а более конкретный ответ требует более конкретного описания ситуации (ну та же SQLite, например)

Comment: Обсуждения на Хешкоде не приветствуются к сожалению, а дискуссия скорее всего выйдет приличная, т.к. тематика задачи довольно нетривиальная.

Comment: @Merlin Что значить "весь он в оперативку на влезет точно"? И, кстати, кто такой SDD (у меня такого нет)? Т.е. массив не влезает в 128Гб? И если да, то на каком же оборудовании Вы собираетесь решать задачу и за какое время? И стоит ли за такой супер-мега-проект браться?

(Напомните, на скольки сотнях персоналок изначально свой MapReduce google-то гонял?)

Comment: @alexlz, думаю @Merlin имел в виду SSD (твердотельный накопитель 128GB), а не Суданский динар.

Кстати, хороший PCI-X ускоритель IO (по сути на технологии SSD) на 1TB стоит всего-то порядка 30K USD.

Comment: @alexlz можете оставить при себе свое мнение насчет проекта. Я поставил вполне четко заданный вопрос.

> каким образом лучше всего хранить
> многомерный динамический массив(
> размером от 120Гб до 8 - 20 Тб), а так
> же получать доступ к его элементам, не
> загружая при этом весь массив в
> оперативную память?
> 
> Главное условие - быстрый доступ
> чтения к элементам массива, **остальное
> неважно**. На крайний случай можно любой
> язык программирования, не только C#

Это и есть проблема, если Вы её не видите то не разводите пожалуйста демагогию. 

ПК - обычный среднестатистический десктоп.

Comment: @Merlin Я действительно не понимаю вопроса. Пытаюсь уточнить с помощью наводящих вопросов, получаю "не разводите демагогию". Ваши цели -- это Ваши цели и мне до них дела нет. Но вот объяснить "не загружая весь массив в оперативную память" Вы не желаете. Если массив существенно (`double [1000, 10000, 10000]`) больше оперативной памяти, установленной на компьютере, то как я его могу весь туда загрузить? Одновременно -- никак, неодновременно -- нельзя по условиям задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если массив "плотный", то быстро (хотя, зависит от способа использования) работать не получится.

Разряженный же (подавляющее большинство элементов нули (или какое-то другое, предопределенное значение)) можно хранить в хэш-таблице с ключем из индексов.

Comment: Спасибо. А хранение и доступ к элементам массива не в оперативной памяти как осуществить?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Например можно хранить в СУБД. 

Но скорее всего надо придумать формат файла (прямого доступа) в котором можно эффективно хранить хэш-таблицу. Тут просто будет проблема эффективного доступа к коллизиям. Надо придумать такой фформат, чтобы элементы коллизий попадали по возможности в одну "запись" на диске (в общем чтобы их можно было читать одним read-ом).

Comment: @Merlin, как я понял из других комментариев, Вы собираетесь использовать SSD. Идея хорошая, особенно в плане хранения структур  прямого доступа, правильный подход к формату может оказаться другим, по сравнению с HDD, но насколько мне известно там есть подводные камни с производительностью. 

Известно, что журналы Oracle размещать на SSD не рекомендуется (на HDD оказывается быстрее).

Правда лично мне экспериментировать с ними (SSD и т.п.) пока не довелось.

Comment: @avp сторонние бд не пока не хочу использовать, попробую как Вы и порекомендовали поэкспериментировать с форматом файла. Скажите пожалуйста вот эта статья подходит под решение? http://habrahabr.ru/post/124900/  Ни разу не сталкивался с форматами файлов.

Comment: Посмотрел статью в хабре. Не думаю, что это Ваш случай. Я имел в виду форматы двоичных файлов (без претензий на кроссплатформенность). Т.е. формат, который быстро (почти без преобразований) читается-пишется. Что-то, с чем можно работать напрямую системными read/write/lseek.

Естественно, адреса частей файла, прочитанных в память надо настраивать. Внутри частей возможно  получится хранить некие смещения (индексы) и работать с ними, а не с непосредственно указателями.

Вообще-то говоря это, я видимо подразумеваю скорее реализацию на Си.